# dataframe calculate mean and convert columns for certain index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','A','A','C','A','A','B','B','M','B','M','M','M','A','A','A'],
                       'ID2':[1,2,3,1,1,1,6,7,1,2,2,5,6,1,2,4]})
df_test
```

[image: df_test]

I want to obtain a new dataframe like this:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'ID1_convert':['A1','B1','A2'],
                       'mean_ID2':[1.5,4,2.33]})
df_result
```

[image]

the column 'ID1_convert' in df_result could be obtained by the column 'ID' in df_test.
for 'A1', 1.8 is the mean of index 0 to 5. because A in the column 'ID1' follow the regular expression r'A{2,}C{0,2}A{1,}'. because it's the first series, it will be assigned to another ID A1.
it is similar to the B.
Therefore, 1.8 is the mean of index 0 to 5. 4.0 is the mean of index 6 to 9. 3.5 is the mean of the index 13 to 15.

I can get all the index tuple list, like [(0,5), (6,9), (13,15)] by a loop. but I have no idea of how to calculate the mean using this tuple list without using a loop.

Comment: Which values are you taking the mean of to end up with 1.8?

Comment: So sorry. It's my mistake. as well as the A2. It should be 1.5 and 2.33 for A1 and A2, respectively. 1.5 is the mean of ID2 in df_test from index 0 to 5. 1.5=(1+2+3+1+1+1)/6

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the indices, you could do something like the following.

```
tup_list = [(0,5),(6,9),(13,15)]

df_test['gp'] = np.nan
for i in range(len(tup_list)):
    a,b = tup_list[i]
    df_test.loc[a:b,'gp'] = i
print(df_test.groupby(by=['gp']).mean())
```

Result:

```
          ID2
gp           
0.0  1.500000
1.0  4.000000
2.0  2.333333
```

1.5 is the mean for the first group, 4.0 is the mean for the second, and 2.333 is the mean for the third.

Comment: en, It's just a test. Actually, the length of the tuple is at least 10.  So, I must use a loop to obtain my result?

Comment: @Jiao I changed it so that it loops over the tuples. You could create a function that produces the group number instead of running a loop and then use `.apply()`, but I'm not sure if that will be much faster.